# Jenkins loses all data when rebooting pc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

I am currently learning Jenkins and how to utilize continuous integration. I am having an issue where all of my data/config files are reset after rebooting my PC. Has anyone had similar issues or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sincerely, I didn't have this problem it's somehow strange because Jenkins, as I know, stores all the configurations in config.xml files in the installation directory. Not sure if it'll help you, but after a restart, if your data doesn't appear to be indexed in Jenkins, go to "Configure" and  there you'll find "Reload configuration from disk".

What I didn't understood from your question:

1. after a restart of Jenkins+ PC, you data+settings don't appear in Jenkins GUI? Or they are also missing from the config.xml file from the installation directory. For example, if you create a user and a job, after a restart this settings are missing only from the  GUI or also from config.xml & jobs directory.
2. How do you run Jenkins? You start Jenkins from Eclipse, you have it installed on your PC.
3. Does Jenkins have permissions to create/edit files in the installation directory? Be aware that after install, Jenkins creates a default username "JENKINS" and will try to edit files and create directories with that username on your PC.

Comment: 1. Yes they are missing (default).
2. I have installed on my server (Ubuntu 14.10 Server)
3. I am not sure I simply followed there [link](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu)

Comment: yes, they don't tell anything about the permissions on files. One thing you can check is the log to see if there are any java exceptions that prevent the saving of data/settings to files and what generates them.  Check /etc/sysconfig/jenkins to see the JENKINSUSER and if it's different from yours or another one that have account on that pc, change it. I wrote a guide to do this>>http://goo.gl/FKO0MC. I suspect that the problem is that Jenkins has the default username "jenkins" and cannot create files in /var/lib/. Hope I could help you!

Comment: You were right and it is now saving. Thank you very much!